# UK Visa Re-Refused After Decision Withdrawal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My wife is British and I applied for a Settlement Visa from outside the UK which Home Office refused, I appealed against the Home Office decision in Tribunal and a few days before hearing the Home Office decided to withdraw and grant entry clearance to me.

Then I received an email from Home Office asking to pay the Immigration Health Surcharge and submit the passport for a visa stamp in my country, which I did on time.

Now after about 10 week when I inquired about the visa they replied that the visa application has been re-refused and I have a right to appeal against this re-refusal.

I want to know if Home Office can re-refuse my application after withdrawing the case in tribunal? Because if they can, I am stuck in a vicious cycle.

Has anyone faced a similar situation? What was the outcome?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't handle questions about settlement visas here. You may want to ask on our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: `I want to know if Home Office can re-refuse my application after withdrawing the case in tribunal?` Well obviously they can, they did it to you.

Comment: so after repeated contacts by my solicitor and a long wait, i finally got visa in a few month ago, home office withdrew case back Dec 2017, so a long wait.